# What is the "œ" doing here?

Tags: word-choice

In *The Wealth of Nations*, the word economy appears frequently (as it should, being a book on economics). However, once (so far), it has been spelled *œconomy*. Upon researching the term, it's the archaic spelling of *economy*. Why would Adam Smith have used two spellings of *economy*? Are/were there slight distinctions between the meanings?

As an aside, a Google Ngram [search](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C5%93conomy,economy&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3%20%22search) shows no usage of *œconomy*.

Comment: Mahnax, @Henry: As to the Ngram, it may be helpful to note that though *œconomy* is rare, *[oeconomy](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oeconomy%2C%C5%93conomy&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)* actually rivals *economy* before 1800.

Comment: See also footnote 1 on page 274 of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=txIvwd48dswC&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=%22%C5%93conomy%22+%22%C5%93%22++ligature&source=bl&ots=GCxFPrrZ0d&sig=FWnSV354FKlyVSf408cAOpXHOFw&hl=en&ei=n2-qTtavKtLG8QPviu3BCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22%C5%93conomy%22%20%22%C5%93%22%20%20ligature&f=false).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Ngram does show [some use of *œconomy*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C5%93conomy&year_start=1700&year_end=1850&corpus=0&smoothing=3) around 1750-1800 and there may be more if Google's book scanners have problems with the *œ*: [*conomy*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conomy&year_start=1700&year_end=1850&corpus=0&smoothing=3) also appears, often [when *œconomy* was intended](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22conomy%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1750,cd_max:1800&lr=lang_en) .

*The Wealth of Nations* was published in 1776, so it quite possible that a typesetter put the *œ* because he thought that may have been what was intended.

Answer (score 6):

The word has had many spellings since its first appearance in the fifteenth century as *yconomie*. *Oeconomie* is found in the fifteenth and sixteenth centuries, and *oeconomy* is found from the fifteenth century onwards. The *oe* is presumably influenced by the classical Latin *oeconomia*, which would have had particular appeal in the eighteenth century.